# Can TraCI and Veins run in parallel?

Tags: omnet++, veins

Is it possible to change the behavior of a single vehicle such as lane change and speed with TraCI and make vehicle-to-vehicle communication with Veins possible?
I'm sorry if there are some points that are difficult to read because of automatic translation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is entirely possible. TraCI can change how single cars behave in SUMO (all commands are documented on https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/TraCI.html). Veins is designed to run a network simulation of hosts that move like cars in SUMO (full set of features is on http://veins.car2x.org/).